# How do I provide random input to the function I want to benchmark?

Tags: java, random, input, benchmarking, jmh

I've creating a new encryption algorithm. Its totally unbreakable and extremely fast. I call it ROT-13. Now I want to do some benchmark tests on it to prove my speed. However I don't just want to encrypt and decrypt the same plaintext over and over, because that will lead to branch prediction that wouldn't happen in reality; instead I want to generate some random plaintext outside the measured function and inject it in.

I thought I could do something like

```
public class Rot13Benchmark{
    public String plaintext;

    @Setup(Level.invocation)
    public void setup(){
        plaintext = randomString();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String rot13Benchmark(){
        return rot13(plaintext);
    }
}
```

But according to the docs on `Level.invocation` -

> WARNING: HERE BE DRAGONS!
>
> ...
>
> This level is only usable for benchmarks that take more than a millisecond...

Since invocations of `rot13` are not expected to take more than a millisecond, it doesn't seem like this is the right pick for me.

What is the correct way to provide random input to my JMH benchmark function such that the random input generation time is not counted towards the benchmark?

Comment: ROT-13?  Have you tried applying ROT-13 twice for double the security?  :D

Comment: Pre-generate a data set in setup. Rotate through the input or pick the next item at random. The question then becomes what kind of input best reflects your use case in terms of memory access pattern. No one can answer that question for you...

Answer (score 1):

How about create a state class in scope of Thread that on setup will create and cache a bunch of strings and then would spit them out in public method one after another.

Obvious cons are:
1. It would require to estimate how many strings need to be prepared before execution.
2. It will include the execution of get method in benchmark but you could benchmark get method alone in the next step and analyze the differences.

It's not ideal solution but best i come up with.

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class InputClass {
    public List<String> testList;
    int index = 0;

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setUp() {

        testList = //generation of random elements;
    }
    public String get(){
        return testList.get(index++);
    }
}
@Benchmark
public void rot13Benchmark(InputClass inputClass){
    return rot13(inputClass.get());
}
```

Comment: Unless your list is small (like a few hundred strings) and you wrap around, you're going to get L1d cache misses when you access them.  This might not be what the OP wants to microbenchmark.  (Like I commented [on the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431349/how-do-i-provide-random-input-to-the-function-i-want-to-benchmark/57552665#comment101355358_57432141).)  That's probably why you're saying it's not an ideal solution.

Answer (score -1):

just make a random String. This could take some time, because you want to encrypt larger portions, too, don'ty you?

```
RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
          .withinRange('a', 'z')
          .build();
String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);
```

Generate a String, store it, benchmark your algorithm afterwards

```
public class Rot13Benchmark{
    public String plaintext;

    @Setup(Level.invocation)
    public void setup(){
        plaintext = randomString(1000);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String rot13Benchmark(){
        return rot13(plaintext);
    }

    public String randomString(int length){
        RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
          .withinRange('a', 'z')
          .build();
        return generator.generate(length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Store it where? Are you saying to generate a boatload of strings beforehand in some giant list? Thats going to take a lot of resources. You also don't specify how to inject a string into individual benchmark runs.

Comment: you are running a test. SetUp creates one String. Store it in your TestClass as a normal String. Run the Benchmark-Test and refer to that String

Comment: no.... I'm running a benchmark. Are you familiar with [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)? It is not the same as JUnit

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more - my problem is not how to generate a random string. That is trivial. My problem is how to I inject a unique random string that I generate into every invocation of my benchmark function?

Comment: it behaves the same way. Create the Data in the Setup. Use it in your methods. Create 10000 Strings, store them, iterate over the 10000 Strings and you can measure it better than one single String. Measuring one String will provide stupid data - once the CPU is on idle, or on load or IO is used or anything else... with 10000 you get closer to an average

Comment: as I said: generate them before hand, then pick them! https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/

Comment: What if @David's real use-case for this function is on a `String` that's hot in cache, e.g. because it was recently written?  You don't necessarily want to iterate over a big collection of String objects in memory and maybe have L1d cache misses (or worse).  256kiB fast private L2 cache on a modern mainstream x86 should hold 10k strings, so you probably don't see *too* much penalty here.

Comment: It's not an easy problem if the function under test is short and might auto-vectorize.  Modifying the string data with a 32-bit integer increment could create store-forwarding stalls if it's then read right away with SIMD instructions.  (Assuming you can even convince a JVM to emit an asm instruction that does a 32-bit add on 4 bytes of a string.)